Why do we only get an approximate 30 second warning for oil running out?
In my Vauxhall Movano I get a 620 mile warning for Adblue running out, and it will not let me start my engine until I have topped up.
Yet I only get a 30 second warning if I am about to run out of oil, and it will still let me start my engine even if oil is empty.
As running out of Adblue will not destroy the engine, but running out of oil will destroy my livelihood, I personally would prefer to swap the 620 mile Adblue warning with the 30 second oil warning.
Sometimes it is not even possible to stop in 30 seconds, like if you're hurtling down the outside lane of a busy motorway with cars and lorries undertaking you, or maybe a section of motorway that has no hard shoulder.
Why do we only get an approximate 30 second warning for running out of oil?

Under normal conditions, you shouldn’t have to add any oil to your engine between services.
What the oil warning light is telling you is that something has gone drastically wrong, since there is low oil pressure. If the engine runs with low oil pressure, then damage will occur.
Sudden low oil pressure can be caused by a number of reasons including -

Oil pump failure
Oil leak
Neglected servicing

The user manual for the Movano recommends that the engine oil is checked regularly using the engine oil dipstick.  The Movano even has a way of displaying the oil level on the dashboard, but this has to be done before the engine is started.  Once the engine has been started, the oil in the engine sump gets distributed around the engine, so it is no longer possible to measure the quantity of oil in the engine.

Whether Adblue or motor oil, failure to periodically check both is the owner's responsibility. DEF fluid, Adblue, is for diesel emissions and according to your information, gives fair warning to top off the def container. The low oil indicator is warning you to top off motor oil or risk engine damage. Developing a habit of checking fluids should always be part of vehicle ownership before indicators turn on.
